# CSS border merge

Tags: html, css

I created an arrow-up button from two borders, unfortunately
it didn't merge together so I can see how border are stacked on 
each other but they should be together like one element!

```css
#myBtn {
  //display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 10px solid #778293;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 4vh;
  height: 4vh;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 1em;
  border-right-width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">My Button</button>
```

Comment: Provide pen please.

Comment: Please don't provide a pen, but use the SO snippet. I have edited your question with a working one, but your code seems to not do what you described, so I am guessing, you are missing some

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 10px solid #778293;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 4vh;
  height: 4vh;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 1em;
  border-right-width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">My Button</button>
```